# What is the minimum duration of validity for a New Zealand tourist visa?

Tags: tourist-visas, new-zealand

I am an Indian citizen and planning to visit New Zealand in next month but haven't decided my duration of stay (but it is likely to be from 1 to 4 weeks).

What would be the minimum duration of validity for a New Zealand tourist visa. Is it three months, or will I only get the visa for the mentioned dates in the application form?

Comment: Whats your nationality?

Comment: oops! I forgot to mention it. Indian BTW

Comment: Thanks :) I asked because NZ has a visa waiver program,  but unfortunately India is not on the list!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visitor Visas are typically issued for [3-month validity](https://www.govt.nz/browse/immigration-and-visas/applying-for-a-visitors-visa/how-to-apply-for-a-visitors-visa/).

> **How long you can stay**
>
> A general visitor visa (tourist visa) will normally allow you to stay in NZ for 3 months.

There is conflicting guidance on this however, as [official sources also state](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/visitor-visa#https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/visa-factsheet/conditions/visitor-visa):

> You can visit New Zealand as a genuine tourist for up to 9 months in an 18-month period.

and

> **How long can you visit for?**
>
> Unless otherwise stated under special instructions,
> visitors to New Zealand are limited to a maximum
> stay of nine months on a visitor visa.

[August 2017 Visitor Visa Guide INZ 1018](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/documents/forms-and-guides/inz1018.pdf) page 4

Comment: Thanks for replying. So, It doesn't matter whether I am going to apply for one month or two weeks. right? I will get the visa for 3 months only.

Comment: @AmitPal unless they are very concerned about you, you will get a standard visitor visa which should cover your needs.

Comment: @AmitPal I would advise stating the longer period when you apply - immigration officials fully understand that travel plans can and do change, so returning home early isn't an issue, they are more looking for longer stays than requested as those are more indicative of immigration issues.

Comment: I don't know if India is included in this, but most Commonwealth countries get a 6-month visitor visa as standard in New Zealand.

Comment: @Crazymoomin if you mean the visa waiver, only British passport holders get the 6 month visa, everyone else on the list gets 3 months. If you mean a visitor visa application, there may be a standard period given for commonwealth countries but it's not documented anywhere.

Comment: This isn't conflicting guidance at all. Each visa gives you up to 3 months before you have to leave. If you leave and come back, and leave and come back, and ... then your running total cannot be more than 9 out of 18 consecutive months. Or another way, if you're only entering on tourist visa, you must spend at least half of any 18 month period outside the country.